# Novel where flying through rainbow results in time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, novel

This story involves a rainbow and time travel. In this story, there is a man with his daughter(around 5 years old) and a nanny. I think he runs an aircraft business. His daughter always wanted him to fly his aeroplane above the rainbow whenever she spotted one. Once he flies his aircraft above a rainbow and when he passes through the rainbow, he experiences certain strange changes. after this he suddenly finds himself landed in a strange place which is from a different time.He finds himself in a land which is almost a century old.He realizes he has travelled 100 years back in time. He meets a girl there and falls in love with her. At that time technology had not developed.

At the end of the story he takes this woman back to his time, flying through the rainbow. He meets his daughter and nanny waiting for him and they all live happily ever after.

Please help me identify the name of this novel.....

Comment: Do you remember if it was a children's book?

Comment: And could you estimate the publishing time-period?

Comment: It was a teenagers book.

Comment: Publishing period should be around 1980s

Answer (score 6):

### Could this be *[Across the Rainbow](http://timetravelromancewriters.com/bookinfo.cfm?BookID=5548)*?

> His Flight of Fancy For seasoned pilot David Terrell, nothing seemed
>   more foolish than flying into a rainbow to wish for a wife. But the
>   down-to-earth widower would do anything for his little girl, Jamie,
>   and she would settle for nothing less than a fairy-tale princess as a
>   mother. So to humor his six-year-old, David flew into the next rainbow
>   he saw and emerged in 1886 Wyoming.

We have a pilot, time travel by flying through a rainbow, and a six-year-old who wants him to fly into said rainbow.

And indeed, the pilot and his love, Analisa, return to his time and "they all live happily ever after." (Word for word).

> "Really? That's neat." Then Jamie heard this really weird noise from
>   inside the plane. "What's that, Daddy?"
>
> "Another surprise," he said, and he laughed as Princess Analisa's
>   cheeks turned pink.
>
> Jamie climbed into the plane and looked in the back. Then she turned
>   around and clapped. "Aunt Holly, come look! Daddy brought home a real
>   princess and the goose that laid the golden egg."
>
> And everyone laughed. Jamie knew that now they'd live happily ever
>   after.